# Are there SDRs that will let me program with a PC and then run a particular program on their own?

Tags: gnuradio, redhawksdr, software-defined-radio

I'd like to program a transmitter to output a routine each time a button is pressed. That way I don't have to be connected to a computer each time I want to use it.  Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are embedded devices like the Ettus E-Series you can set up to do this. Note you'll need some experience in embedded systems if you want to use such a system. However, for low-performance apps (e.g. low-bandwidth signals) you might be able to simply run a GRC flow graph on your embedded device without a lot of modifications.